# c++ multithreading class methods

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, methods

I have following problem.

```
vector<thread> vThreads;

list<Crob *> lRobs;
list<Crob *>::iterator i;

for(i = lRobs.begin(); i != lRobs.end(); i++)
{
    vThreads.push_back(thread((*i)->findPath));
}
```

I want to pass the method findPath to a thread, but I just get a lot of errors...

```
> labrob.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
labrob.cpp:72:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
labrob.cpp:72:43: note: candidates are:
In file included from labrob.cpp:14:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:131:7: note: std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (Crob::*)(); _Args = {}]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:131:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘int (Crob::*&&)()’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:126:5: note: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:126:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::thread&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:122:5: note: std::thread::thread()
/usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:122:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [labrob.o] Error 1
```

I have already tried to pass local functions and that worked without problems...

**Added CRob header**

```
#pragma once
#include "point.hpp"
#include "lab.hpp"

class Crob
{
  protected:
   Cpoint *pos;
   int steps;
   Clab *labfind;
   string direction;

  public:
   Crob(Clab *lab);
   virtual ~Crob();
   virtual void findPath(); 
   void moveTo(int x, int y);   
   void moveToPrint(int x, int y);  
   int getSteps(void);
   void checkDirection();
};
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Crob`?

Comment: You should use `std::bind()` to pass this method to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to pass a non-static method to the std::thread constructor.  You cannot do that: a non-static methods needs a object so it can be called.  Looks like you want:

```
for(i = lRobs.begin(); i != lRobs.end(); i++)
{
    vThreads.push_back(std::thread(&Crob::findPath, *i));
}
```

Comment: ah, thank you very much!

but how do I get exact the object from my list?

or do I get it with *i?

I still get an error though...

labrob.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
labrob.cpp:72:35: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘virtual void Crob::findPath()’
make: *** [labrob.o] Error 1

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to call the constructor